# Tensorflow Mobile - Inference Interface

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I have some problems with TensorflowInferenceInterface. After tensorflow model loading I need shape dimensions of output node. In Tensorboard dashboard there is correctly represented the following shape: [?,?,?,2048] because dynamic image inputs. I have executed these instructions for inference process:

---

```
TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(assetManager, MODEL_NAME);
Operation operation = inferenceInterface.graph().operation(OUTPUT_NAME);

inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NAME, floatValues, 1, bitmapImage.getWidth(), bitmapImage.getHeight(), 3);

String[] outputNames =  new String[] {"activation_43/Relu"};
    inferenceInterface.run(outputNames, true);

float[] outputs = new float[690000];

inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NAME, outputs);
```

---

My question is: how can I obtain output tensor dimensions? I need int value of each field in the shape vector instead of question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when one does inference, the output shapes are all static. It seems like TensorflowInferenceInterface was designed with this case in mind and does not have a way to get output shapes.

One option is to copy paste the source code (it is fairly small and uses only other public interfaces) and make `getTensor()` public. Then, you can do:

```
Tensor<?> t = inferenceInterface.getTensor(OUTPUT_NAME);
long[] dimensions = t.shape();
```

Alternatively, you can submit a github issue describing your use case. Folks might find it reasonable and accept a PR to change the actual `getTensor()` method visibility or suggest an alternative.

Comment: it's a private method inside TensorflowInferenceInterface... how can I do?

Comment: How Can I override that method in order to make it public? I have copy paste the source code of TensorflowInferenceInterface and i have modified visibility from private to public but I obtained a compilation error like this: "getTensor() has private access in org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorflowInferenceInterface". The library is linked in build.gradle file. Is it that one the problem? Can you help me? Thanks @iga

Comment: @M.Armao, it seems like you are not getting the code you copy-pasted. FYI, if there are multiple classes with the same name, Java class loader can technically pick any. Usually the last loaded one is picked. You can rename it and use the new class name in your code to be sure you get the right class.